Why does this code generate an Ansible deprecation warning?
# Build a list of Adtran AP mac addresses found on directly connected switch ports
- name: PARSE AND FILTER MAC ADDRESS-TABLE
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    macs: "{{ macs + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ macs_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_mac-address-table.textfsm') }}"
  when:
    - item.DESTINATION_PORT[0] not in neighbors.keys()   # Ignore macs found on neighboring switches
    - item.DESTINATION_ADDRESS is search('^0019\.92.*$')   # Ignore macs that aren't Adtran APs

I get the following deprecation warning:
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Use 'ansible.utils.hwaddr' module instead. This feature will be removed from ansible.netcommon in a release after 2024-01-01. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by
 setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.6]
  config file = /workspaces/git/my-repo/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/vscode/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/vscode/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/python/current/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.6 (main, Dec 19 2023, 21:21:06) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/local/python/3.11.6/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.4
  libyaml = True

Why?

Which version of Ansible are you using?

@OrtomalaLokni Updated the post with that info. Thanks.

hwaddr, part of the ipaddr set of filters was moved.  Twice, from to pre-collections ansible to ansible.netcommon then to ansible.utils. They did not want to tie generally useful netaddr based utilities to the manage network gear code in ansible.netcommon.
As the warning says,  ansible.utils is the name to use. Search everything for hwaddr filter references.

I don't know why, but the deprecation warning always appeared in the above task, but hwaddr was not used in that task at all. It was used, however, in several other tasks. It appears I am running in to the issue described here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/77971
Not using the fully qualified module name results in Ansible picking the deprecated version. I was able to change it to ansible.utils.hwaddr and the warning went away.

To me it would cause less confusion to have the ansible-core redirects to go ansible.utils.  Which has not happened in core yet for whatever reason. As I recall, this was the first example of double redirects, from core then from a collection.
